# compare two json and return unique key from first json java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson, compare

currently i have two json body :
1. globaljson
2. companyjson

globaljson :

```
"dS": {
      "a": 5,
      "b": false,
      "c": 5,
      "d": false,
      "e": 1,
      "f": 5,
      "g": 33.528,
      "h": false
    }
```

company json :

```
 "dS": {
    "a": 90
  },
```

expected output :

```
 "dS": {
          "a": 90,
          "b": false,
          "c": 5,
          "d": false,
          "e": 1,
          "f": 5,
          "g": 33.528,
          "h": false
        }
```

i tried to do following :

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = mapper.readValue(companyjson, Map.class);
Map<String, Object> map2 = mapper.readValue(globaljson, Map.class);
Map<String, Object> merged = new HashMap<String, Object>(map1);
merged.putAll(map2);
```

but this returns

```
"dS": {
    "a": 90
  },
```

im currently using jackson library but couldn't find any method that solves my requirement. i don't want to hard code my keys because key name may change in future.

Comment: The key of the outer JSON object is `dS` and not the inner objects like `"a" ,etc. Thus, you're replacing the value of `dS`. Do you understand that? It should be quite obvious.

Comment: Dont see anything wrong . Can you try convertvalue instead of readvalue method . And I assume you verified map1 and map2 before merging.

Answer (score 0):

Before merging ...

- `map1` must be: `{dS={a=90}}`
- `map2` must be: `{dS={a=5, b=false, c=5, d=false, e=1, f=5, g=33.528, h=false}}`

Then after this line ...

```
Map<String, Object> merged = new HashMap<String, Object>(map1);
```

.... `merged` must be: `{dS={a=90}}`

Then after this line ...

```
merged.putAll(map2);
```

... `merged` must be `{dS={a=5, b=false, c=5, d=false, e=1, f=5, g=33.528, h=false}}` since the effect of `putAll` is to replace the value of the key `dS` in `merged` with the value of the key `dS` in `map2`. To put it another way; you are merging two maps which both contain a key named `dS` and hoping that the merge is sensitive to the **contents** of `dS` whereas the merge actually just replaces the value of one `dS` with the value of the other `dS`.

To get your desired result you have to *merge the maps which exist under the `dS` keys*, for example:

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = mapper.readValue(companyJson, Map.class);
Map<String, Object> map2 = mapper.readValue(globalJson, Map.class);

Map<String, Object> globalMap = (Map) map2.get("dS");
Map<String, Object> companyMap = (Map) map1.get("dS");
globalMap.putAll(companyMap);
```

The above code results in `map2` having the following contents:

```
{dS={a=90, b=false, c=5, d=false, e=1, f=5, g=33.528, h=false}}
```

Comment: yes that works but i dont want to hard code key names in my code because json keys may change in future so i was looking for a way so that i can get rid of hard coding key names.

Comment: You cannot `putAll` and expect that command to be sensitive to the contents of `dS` or to put it another way; you can only merge the contents of `dS` if you _deal with `dS`_ and this requires either knowing the name of the key or applying some sort of interrogation technique such as: 'iterate over the key set and if you find a value of type Map then merge it with the value for the same key name in the other map'.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use `JsonNode` instead of `Map` and jackson mapper to perform merge.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(json1, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode node2 = mapper.readValue(json2, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode result  = mapper.updateValue(node, node2);

// if you really need a map
Map merged = mapper.convertValue(result, Map.class);
```

Alternative version

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(json1, JsonNode.class);
ObjectReader updater = mapper.readerForUpdating(node);
JsonNode result = updater.readValue(json2);
```